# Using django and django-voting app, how can I order a queryset according to the votes of each item?

Tags: django, sql-order-by, django-voting

(I'm new to python and django so please bear with me for a second. I apologise if this has been answered elsewhere and couldn't find it)

Let's say I have a Link model and through the django-voting application users can vote on link instances. How can I order those link instances according to their score, eg. display those with the higher score first.

I assume I could use the get_top manager of django-voting, but that would only give me the top scoring link instances and wouldn't take into consideration other parameters I would like to add (for example, those links that belong to a specific user or paging or whatever).

My guess would be to write a custom manager for my Link model where by I can filter a queryset according to each item's score. If I understand correctly that will require me to loop through each item, check its score, and then place it a list (or dictionary) which will then be sorted according to the score of each item. That wouldn't return a queryset but a dictionary with each item.

Am I missing something here?

edit:

Here's a stripped-down version of the Link model:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)  
    date = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True )
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    links = ValidLinkManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
```

and when a user votes I have this in my view:

```
Vote.objects.record_vote(link, user, vote)
```

where link is the Link instance, user is an instance of auth.User and vote is either 1, 0, or -1.
The ValidLinkManager just filters out those links that have is_deleted set to True.

Comment: Can you post some code, possibly what your Link model looks like...?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here. Are you just trying to order the display of the votes?

Comment: No, I want to order a Link queryset according to the score/votes of each item. The goal is to display items that have the highest score first.

Answer (score 1):

The `get_top` method in VoteManager isn't that complicated. Look at its code (in managers.py:122). You can easily create a version of it that accepts a filter as another parameter and applies it to the "objects" queryset after it creates it, in line 158 - this way you can add other filters like the ones you're missing.

Maybe you can also offer that as a patch back to the jonathan, and he'll put it in django-voting :)

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use a generic relation in my model:

```
votes = generic.GenericRelation(Vote)
```

and then to aggregate it:

```
my_model.objects.annotate(num_votes=Count('votes'))
```

In this case I am just counting the number of votes received by the objects, but you can switch `Count` with `Avg` to get an average.

Since [this does not work with Django by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-and-aggregation), I installed [`django-generic-aggregation`](https://github.com/coleifer/django-generic-aggregation).